# Remove tr in table by ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have i probléme in removing tr in a table, I Need to fill a table by ajax, i create tr with id and i call a function that call ajax to retrieve tds tags. i have two case when response equal 0 and when response is différente to 0.
My script :

```
       <script>
            function get_tr(id,name,lastname){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '../ajax.php',
                    data: 'id=' + id + '&name=' + name + '&lastname=' + lastname,
                    success: function(response){
                          if(response == 0){
                              $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                          }else if(response != 0){
                            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = response; 
                          }
                     }
                 });
            }
        </script>
```

And this is my loop to fill the table

```
<table id="tbl1" class="datatable" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" width="100%">

        <tr>
            <th width="15%">Name</th>

            <th width="15%">Lastname</th>

        </tr>
    <?php       

    $queryresult = mysql_query("SELECT id,name,lastname FROM tbl");

    while ($data = mysql_fetch_object($queryresult)) 
        { 
            $id = $data->id;
            $name = $data->name;
            $lastname = $data->lastname;
        ?>
        <tr id="<?php echo $id; ?>" >
        <script>get_tr(<?php echo $id; ?>, <?php echo $name; ?>, <?php echo $lastname; ?> );</script>
        </tr>
 <?php } ?>


</table>
```

The probleme is here in script :

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

When i want remove the tr with response : 0 it don't work

Comment: $(this) inside the success function does not refer to the tr element. You can remove the element by specifing the id such as $("id").remove()

Comment: It looks like you are making an ajax call for every single row. Why would you want to do that? I don't see a reason to make an ajax call at all here, you can easily build your html in your `while` loop.

Comment: Because i need to execute a php function in ajax.php that filter if tr must be shown or no. So i musn't remove success function

Answer (score 1):

You can't use **this** inside your success function. Why you don't want use simple `$('#'+id).remove()` in your `get_tr` function?

Comment: Because i need to execute a php function in ajax.php that filter if tr must be shown or no. So i musn't remove success function

Comment: Also because i have mot than 4000 tr in my loop, Ajax will optimize the page loading i guess

Comment: You don't need remove success function, you must use row id to remove it or no. `$.ajax({
                    ...
                    success: function(response){
                          if(response == 0){
                              $('#'+id).remove();
                          }else if(response != 0){
                            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = response; 
                          }
                     }
                 });
            `

Comment: You use id in your `response!=0` branch, you must also use id in your `response==0` branch